# How to disable the menu button function while my Mobile App is active

Tags: android

We are trying to build an Android App that only shows the blank screen with a logo, when Mobile App is active. App gets active when user click on the Active button and should get automatically inactive after 15 minutes. Once the mobile app get inactive is should go back to the normal screen (screen with menu icons). But the problem we are facing is, when user click on the Menu button, it takes back to the menu screen on the phone, while the mobile app is active. Main purpose of this app is, not let user to use any function on the phone when this app is in active mode (during the 15 minutes period). Please help!!!

Comment: why not use Android Kiosk mode ? search for it there are own implementations of this like http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/ maybe it´s helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can override the menu option and do nothing or you can show the toast of the message you want user to read